# How to set ID to correspondent to object in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have `Category` that can have `RootCategory`. Problem is that it does not set `RootCategoryID` properly, instead it is creating `Category_ID` in database that I don't even made in my model.

It does map everything like I expect it to if I don't have modified `get` on RootCategory by the way. But then `RootCategory` is always null (he does not know where to get it from)

Model

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // Tried [ForeignKey("RootCategoryID")]
    public Category RootCategory {
        get
        {
            ORDataContext _db = new ORDataContext();
            return _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == this.RootCategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public int? RootCategoryID { get; set; } // This does not set itself properly

    public ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Generated database after `update-database`

```
-ID
-RootCategoryID (that I have created, but it's not used)
-Category_ID (taht EF created for me, that I don't want)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to manuallyload the nav property `RootCategory` like you have, EF will do it automatically.  However, EF is having trouble inferring what you're wanting, you should map it explicitly either with data annotations:

```
   public class Category
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }

      public virtual Category RootCategory { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("RootCategory")]
      public int? RootCategoryID { get; set; } // This does not set itself properly

      public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }    

   }
```

or via fluent:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
        .HasMany( c => c.ChildCategories )
        .WithOptional( ca => ca.RootCategory )
        .HasForeignKey( c => c.RootCategoryID );
  }
```

And all your properties/collections should work.

Comment: If I try annotations example it returns `RootCategory` as `null` all the time.

Comment: @Qmal - try adding the `virtual` keyword to the association properties (`ChildCategories` and `RootCategory`) to enable lazy-loading.  Entity Framework will then load the associated entities as needed.

Comment: BTW is there any way I can do this without even setting `RootCategoryID` or it is mandatory to perform what I want?

Comment: @Qmal - if you want to set the RootCategory of another Category, you can do something like this: `childCategory.RootCategory = parentCategory` or `parentCategory.ChildCategories.Add(childCategory)`.  You can still use the RootCategoryID property, but you don't necessarily have to.